# OneSignal Disable notification for a period of time

Tags: cordova, push-notification, notifications, onesignal

At the moment in my clientSide, I'm able to disable / enable the notification, is there a way to disable notification for 1 hour or 2 hours ?

Answer (score 0):

For schedule enable/disable notifications first you need to implement Alarmmanager. After that you can set schedule for notification enable or disable time.

Once you setup alarm manager then you can put your onesignal notification code OneSignal.setSubscription(true or false) to alarm receiver callback to enable or disable notification. Even you can set multiple schedules.

For example :
Disable notification from 10 pm to 6 am 
or 
Disable notification till 3 hours from now etc..